# Troubleshooting VPC flow logs with an S3 bucket using SSE-KMS encryption with CMK

Tags: terraform, amazon-s3, aws-vpc, amazon-kms

I'm using Terraform and trying to set up automatic export of VPC flow logs into an S3 bucket in the same AWS account and region (ca-central-1) that has default encryption turned on with AWS-KMS (using a CMK). Even after trying many permutations of policies for KMS and the S3 bucket, the flow logger still always ends up in `Access error` status.

**Update**: When the S3 bucket is reconfigured to use AES-256 as the default encryption (instead of KMS) the VPC flow logs get written normally. So it's definitely a KMS problem.

The `aws_flow_log` Terraform resource is configured exactly according to the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/flow_log.html).

```
resource "aws_flow_log" "vpc_flow_log" {
  log_destination_type = "s3"
  log_destination      = "${aws_s3_bucket.awslogs.arn}"
  traffic_type         = "ALL"
  vpc_id               = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  depends_on           = ["aws_s3_bucket_policy.awslogs"]
}
```

[image: A cropped screenshot of the Flow Logs tab in VPC console showing Status in Access error with a pop-up saying The log destination is not accessible.]

And the result of `aws ec2 describe-flow-logs`:

```
{
  "CreationTime": "2020-05-15T16:22:40.142Z",
  "DeliverLogsErrorMessage": "Access error",
  "DeliverLogsStatus": "FAILED",
  "FlowLogId": "fl-REDACTED",
  "FlowLogStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "ResourceId": "vpc-REDACTED
  "TrafficType": "ALL",
  "LogDestinationType": "s3",
  "LogDestination": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED-awslogs",
  "LogFormat": "${version} ${account-id} ${interface-id} ${srcaddr} ${dstaddr} ${srcport} ${dstport} ${protocol} ${packets} ${bytes} ${start} ${end} ${action} ${log-status}"
}
```

Curiously, it works fine in my second "sandbox" AWS account where I exclusively use the AWS web console, never Terraform. This account is configured the same way with AWS-KMS on the S3 bucket.

Both accounts seem to have the same configuration, so I can't figure out why it works in the sandbox, but fails in my terraformed account.

---

#### S3 bucket

Default encryption is enabled and and Custom KMS arn is selected.

[image]

S3 bucket policy includes statements to allow VPC flow logs delivery from `delivery.logs.amazonaws.com` as written in [Publishing flow logs to Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-s3.html#flow-logs-s3-permissions).

```
    {
        "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryAclCheck",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED-awslogs"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED-awslogs/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED-awslogs/AWSLogs/REDACTED/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
            }
        }
    }
```

#### KMS Key Policy

KMS key policy includes a statement that allows usage by VPC Flow logs as instructed by [Required CMK key policy for use with SSE-KMS buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs-s3.html#flow-logs-s3-cmk-policy).

```
    {
        "Sid": "Allow VPC Flow Logs to use the key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:ReEncrypt",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "kms:Decrypt"
        ]
    }
```

---

I'm at a loss here. What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing one very important line in my KMS key policy:

```
    resources = ["*"]
```

Now it works fine, and my full policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow VPC Flow Logs to use the key",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:ReEncrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:DescribeKey",
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```